# Draw bubbles to show details in line chart using chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I developed a line chart using chartJS. In my chart, I have to draw the data line, and lines with bubbles to show where is the mode, red, and amber in my data. I have figured how to draw the lines. But I don't understand how to draw the bubbles to show the details.

The chart I need to draw is shown in the picture:

[image: Line chart result]

Is there any idea how to draw the chart ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the simple solution.

There is plugins in chartJS called **chartjs-plugin-annotation.**
These plugins help you make arbitrary lines in the chart and give labels to it.

You can see the example and documentation of chartJS plugin annotation [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation)